# How to use Nuget symbols from network share?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget

Network shares can be used as a Nuget source for packages. This works fine, I would like to debug the nuget packages and step into their source code.

I published a symbol package to a network share, using

`Nuget Push MyPackage.symbols.nupkg -Source "\\network drive\nuget\"`

I can see the symbols package has a `src` folder with the source code files, so the code is included.
How do I step into the source files of the package while debugging? When I try to step into the nuget package, I get a dialog asking me to find the .cs file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO you cannot use network share as symbol server, I tried it once and it didn't work.

You should setup [your own SymbolServer](http://www.xavierdecoster.com/setting-up-your-own-symbolsource-server-step-by-step). I do it in my previous company and it worked like a charm, only problem that you may have is to install properly Windows Debugging Tools.

After you setup SymbolServer and upload nuget's with symbols (nuget pack xxx.csproj -Symbol), you must configure [Visual Studio debugger](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/314186/How-to-use-symbol-server-and-why-you-really-like-t).

Comment: you're right. I ended up on that webpage too after googling. I was able to set it up and debug into source code. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Interesting. This is in contrast to the [MS documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241613.aspx): _4. Any network, internet, or local symbol servers and locations that are specified on, such as the Microsoft symbol server if enabled._ For me it reads that any network location (ie. shared folder) is useable.